# How do I Make Injected Mocks Equal to Null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    SomeObj dummy;
    ...
    public Bar makeBar(){
        if(dummy == null) {
            ...do stuff
        }
        return new Bar(dummy);
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a unit test in the contents of the if statement to make sure my code is doing what it needs to do.

Right now, my unit test looks something like this:

```
public class FooTest {    
    @InjectMocks
    Foo foo;

    @Mock
    SomeObj dummy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        foo = new Foo();

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    ...
    @Test
    public void testMakeBar()
    {
        when(dummy.equals(null)).thenReturn(true);
        ...
        foo.makeBar();
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work which is why I'm here. In short, how do I mock the `==` operator?

Side note: Sorry if this is a dumb question or an easy fix. When trying to google this, I got a lot of "Injected mocks are null" which is actually the opposite of my problem.

Comment: If this is as simple as the example here, you could just create a new Foo in the junit and run it. If, as I imagine, it's much more complex with other dependencies that are needed to get to the point you want to test, you could make a new Foo with @InjectMocks and then in the junit or setup, manually set SomeObj to null.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're over-thinking things. Just stop mocking `dummy`, or stop injecting mocks to `Foo`, and you'll get a `Foo` instance with a `null` `dummy` (since it was never initialized).

Answer (score 0):

If this is as simple as the example here, you could just create a new Foo (ie, actual new Foo() instantiation) in the junit and run it.

If, as I imagine, it's much more complex with other dependencies that are needed to get to the point you want to test, you could make a new Foo with @InjectMocks and then in the junit or setup, manually set SomeObj to null. In this way, you don't have to muck with the other Foo object that is presumably used in other tests.